# How to explain the relation between atomic number and energy of orbitals?

Tags: atomic-structure

I came across a certain line in my textbook that says:

"As the atomic number increases the energy of orbitals decreases"

Can someone please explain how this happens?

My explanation is: As number of protons increases, the increased positive charge pulls the electrons closer to the nucleus, thus reducing the size and energy of the orbitals (since orbitals with lower energy tend to be smaller and closer to the nucleus)

Is my explanation correct? If not can someone please explain it to me in simple words? I have just started getting into chemistry

Answer (score 1):

It is valid, while there is a single electron(*). With more electrons, things get complicated by nucleus charge screening/shilding and mutual electron repulsion. E.g. the $\mathrm{2s}$ electron of $\ce{Li}$ atoms "feels" the effective charge somewhere between $\mathrm{+3e}$ as the true nucleus charge and $\mathrm{+e}$, the nucleus charge perfectly(**) screened off by the $\mathrm{1s}$ electrons. See [Slater's_rules](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater%27s_rules).

---

(*) There is important essential thing: the quantum effects. They  defining the allowed levels of electron energies, that go down for respective orbitals with the raising atomic number. If they had gone up, the stronger nucleus attraction would not have helped.

(**) - That would have happen, if 3D distribution of $\mathrm{1s}$ electrons occurance had been perfectly spherically symmetric AND not overlapping $\mathrm{2s}$ electron distribution, forming exclusive regions for $\mathrm{1s}$ and $\mathrm{2s}$ electron distribution..